# Is this proof for Theorem 28.1. Munkres' <it>Topology</it> correct?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

The following is Theorem 28.1. from Munkres' *Topology*:

[image]

It says that for each $a \in A$ we can choose a neighborhood $U_a$ of $a$ such that $U_a$ intersects $A$ in the point $a$ alone.

Is that an assumption or a result of characteristics that $A$ have? And why that assumption/conclusion is correct?

A counterexample for that is when $A=[a,b]$. $A$ contains all its limit points. We can also determine a set $X$ to be compact and to contain $A$. Any neighborhood of any point in $A$ is open interval meaning that it intersects $A$ is infinitely many points other than the point itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using the assumption that $A$ has no limit points (not merely the statement that $A$ contains all its limit points).  Given any $a\in A$, we know $a$ is not a limit point of $A$.  By definition of "limit point", this means there is an open neighborhood $U_a$ such that $U_a\cap A$ contains no point of $A$ except possibly $a$.  Since $a\in U_a$ and $a\in A$, this means $U_a\cap A=\{a\}$.

Comment: It says "then it contains all its limit points". I don't understand why "has no limit points" and "contains all its limit points" always same?

Comment: They aren't the same.  "Has no limit points" _implies_ "contains all its limit points".  So you start by assuming that $A$ has no limit points, and therefore it contains all its limit points (and therefore is closed).  Next, you use the fact that $A$ has no limit points again to find the set $U_a$.

Comment: Sorry, some confusion! Suppose A=(0,1). Does it have limit points? There are two meanings for **has**: 0 and 1 are the limit points but they are not in A so A 'hasn't' its limit points; other meaning is that is has limit point(s) meaning there're points even **not** in A such that every neighbourhood contains at least one point belonging to a given set.

Comment: "$A$ has limit points" means that there are points of $X$ (possibly in $A$, possibly not in $A$) that are limit points of $A$.

Comment: $A$ has no limit points means that there is no point in $X$ such that every neighborhood of that contains at least one point belonging to $A$. $A$ contains all its limit points means that there is point(s) in $A$, so in $X$, such that every neighborhood of that contains at least one point belonging to $A$. So how "has no limit points" implies "contains all its limit points"?

Comment: $A$ contains all its limit points does not mean what you said.  It means that all points of $X$ which are limit points of $A$ are elements of $A$.  If there are no such points, then this is vacuously true.  (Also, your definition of "limit point" is incorrect: you mean to say every neighborhood of your point $a$ contains a point of $A$ besides $a$ itself.)

Comment: Sorry, one last question. Can you give an example for "Has no limit points implies contains all its limit points" to be true but not vacuously? I can't think of anything but vacuously the implication holds.

Comment: To me, there is only one (false) way to explain it: if $A$ has no limit points then it doesn't have any limit points in $X-A$ so the limit points must be in $A$. But that's not true to say that there are definitely in $A$.

Comment: It is true vacuously, but vacuous truth is just as good as any other truth.  "$A$ contains all its limit points" does NOT mean that $A$ actually contains any of its limit points, it just means that all the limit points that do exist (possibly none) are elements of $A$.

Comment: where do we use that A is closed? for what do we need that A is closed?

Comment: @Isabella: Well, that is how we know $X-A$ is open.